# Why does pacman need to import PGP key during Rofi installation?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, pgp

I installed the Rofi window switcher with pacman this morning on a clean install of Arch linux. During the install it paused and prompted me to import a PGP key as it was searching for keys. Is this legit? I’ve never seen this before with pacman. I was unable to find the developer’s name in Arch’s developer directory. I took a picture of the screen and attached the photo.

[image: Screenshot of GPG prompt]

Why did this happen?

Comment: Please [don't paste text as images](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/117549)

Comment: Hello. At the time I was doing a clean install and had no computer. I made that post with my iPhone. Furthermore, including the picture gave me a degree of comfort because my inquiry involved the name and email of an Arch maintainer. An image provided at least some form of a safety barrier.

Comment: Understood; it would have been a little typing test to re-type that GPG key. I've re-imported the photo; just keep in mind that photos aren't searchable, so it's hard for others to find out if they have the same problem as you did. (Or to be able to read the photo to answer the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Morten was only [recently elected as a Trusted User](https://lists.archlinux.org/pipermail/aur-general/2017-September/033549.html), so in order to install packages that he maintains in [community], you will need to add his key to the keyring.

In other words, what you are seeing is business as usual.

He has been added to the [TU list on the website](https://www.archlinux.org/people/trusted-users/#Foxboron), where you can compare his key.